# Storing boolean in Local storage

Tags: javascript, reactjs, local-storage

When i store a boolean e.g. (true) in local storage and performs an action that changes the value in the local storage from (true) to (false) on reload i want it to still remain that (false) that it is but ends up turning (true). please how can this be done?

I tried seeting it but- still did not work out

Comment: Have you tried to set it in [cookies][1] or [HTML5 web storage][2]? 


  [1]: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/cookies
  [2]: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

Comment: No, I have not, If I try will it work?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74752678/storing-boolean-in-local-storage?noredirect=1#comment131930377_74752678

Comment: It should work. As the JS is client-side every burned-in value is reloaded every time when you load the page. The only solution to remember what was the changes is to use a server with a database or client-side data storage thing which usually can be web storage or cookies. But also you can use blockchain technologies too which are developed for this purpose, but in that case, you should take care of the security of your data.

Comment: Show us your code, otherwise there is no way we can help you debug it. And no need for cookies, localStorage should work, you just probably have a bug somewhere.

Comment: @GuillaumeBrunerie I think this is a theoretical question.

Comment: @GuillaumeBrunerie also he said that he didn't try these kinds of technologies...

Comment: @KorteAlma Well, cookies are meant to be read by the server, which doesn't seem to be the desired behavior here, and web storage consists of localStorage (which OP did test) and sessionStorage (which has the same API as localStorage, so there is no reason it would work better).

Comment: And using web3 or blockchains to simply store a boolean locally is just plain absurd.

Comment: @GuillaumeBrunerie maybe these kinds of tech weren't designed to solve this problem but you can use them for it. And for learning is also a good starting point.

Comment: Just because it is theoretically possible to use something for some purpose doesn't necessarily mean that "you can use that" is a good answer to the question "how do I solve this".

Comment: There are several pages that use these kinds of technologies to store data and you can use them as a single-page static web app, to do something using JS in your browser. Just as an example: jsoneditoronline.org, or many canvas-like websites...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to set it in [cookies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/cookies) or [HTML5 web storage](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp)?

Also you can use web3 technologies like [near](https://near.org/) or [filecoin](https://filecoin.io/build/).

> *As the JS is client-side every burned-in value is reloaded every time when you load the page. The only solution to remember what was the changes is to use a server with a database or client-side data storage thing which usually can be web storage or cookies. But also you can use blockchain technologies too which are developed for this purpose, but in that case, you should take care of the security of your data.*